# I would like to autofill a webform by using the document.getElementByID however whenever I go back to the website, the ID keeps changing

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a javascript injection through a bookmark in google chrome to autofill fields on a website. The code works great but when I go back to the website, the bookmark doesn't work anymore because the ID has changed. I am using the document.getElementby ID function. It works fine on websites where the id is static but on websites where it is dynamic, it doesn't work
How can I solve the problem?

This is the code, xxxx stands for the id.

```
javascript: (function () { 
    function F1(ele, val) { 
        if (document.getElementById(ele) && val != "") { 
             document.getElementById(ele).value = val; 
        } 
    } 
    F1("xxxxx", "yyyyy"); 
})();
```

Comment: There's *probably* a way to uniquely identify the element based on its location in the DOM even if its ID changes, it might be possible to figure something out if there was an example of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

If the ID changes dynamically, we may have to decode its pattern. I would probably suggest to fill using placeholder if the form fields are minimal.
    `document.querySelector('[placeholder="User Id"]').value =1234`
    `document.querySelector('[placeholder="xxxxxx"]').value ='password'`
etc..